# where to place the do while loops for repeating the program?

Tags: c++, loops

i am creating a program that asks for the user's birth date then it prints what day of the week it is. i am done with the code and is now working but i want to add a loop so it can repeat again to ask for user's birth date and i am now stuck to where to put the loops. please help.

this is the code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int JAN_DAYS = 31,
FEB_DAYS = 28,
MAR_DAYS = 31,
APR_DAYS = 30,
MAY_DAYS = 31,
JUN_DAYS = 30,
JUL_DAYS = 31,
AUG_DAYS = 31,
SEP_DAYS = 30,
OCT_DAYS = 31,
NOV_DAYS = 30;
int month, day, year;
int decPrev;
int dayOfWeek;
char date;


int main()
{
    cout << "Input birth date [dd/mm/yyyy] " << endl; //prompts the user to      input their birthdate with the following format
    std::cin >> day >> date >> month >> date >> year;
    cout << "You entered " << month << "/" << day << "/" << year << endl;

    if (day > 0 && day < 32 && month > 0 && month < 13 && year > 0)
    {
        // calculates the day of the week for December 31 of the previous year
        decPrev = ((year-1)*365+((year-1)/4)-((year-1)/100)+((year-1)/400))%7;

        // adds the days of each month before the month entered
        switch(month)
        {
            case 12:
                decPrev += NOV_DAYS;
            case 11:
                decPrev += OCT_DAYS;
            case 10:
                decPrev += SEP_DAYS;
            case 9:
                decPrev += AUG_DAYS;
            case 8:
                decPrev += JUL_DAYS;
            case 7:
                decPrev += JUN_DAYS;
            case 6:
                decPrev += MAY_DAYS;
            case 5:
                decPrev += APR_DAYS;
            case 4:
                decPrev += MAR_DAYS;
            case 3:
                decPrev += FEB_DAYS;
                if (0 == (year % 4)) decPrev += 1;
            case 2:
                decPrev += JAN_DAYS;
            case 1:
                decPrev += day;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        dayOfWeek = decPrev % 7;

        // translates the number value to a string for the day
        switch(dayOfWeek)
        {
            case 0:
                cout << "The day of the week for " << month << "/"
                << day << "/" << year << " is Sunday" << endl;
                break;
            case 1:
                cout << "The day of the week for " << month << "/"
                << day << "/" << year << " is Monday" << endl;
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "The day of the week for " << month << "/"
                << day << "/" << year << " is Tuesday" << endl;
                break;
            case 3:
                cout << "The day of the week for " << month << "/"
                << day << "/" << year << " is Wednesday" << endl;
                break;
            case 4:
                cout << "The day of the week for " << month << "/"
                << day << "/" << year << " is Thursday" << endl;
                break;
            case 5:
                cout << "The day of the week for " << month << "/"
                << day << "/" << year << " is Friday" << endl;
                break;
            case 6:
                cout << "The day of the week for " << month << "/"
                << day << "/" << year << " is Saturday" << endl;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    else cout << "Invalid input." << endl;


    cin.get();
    cin.ignore(); cin.ignore();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Place it just before your first cout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your `while` loop at the beginning of the `main()`, although I would prefer a `do ... while` as this code *has to* execute at least once.

```
int main()
{
    char choice;
    do //your loop begins.
    {
    cout << "Input birth date [dd/mm/yyyy] " << endl; //prompts the user to      input their birthdate with the following format
    std::cin >> day >> date >> month >> date >> year;
    cout << "You entered " << month << "/" << day << "/" << year << endl;

    if (day > 0 && day < 32 && month > 0 && month < 13 && year > 0)
    {
        // calculates the day of the week for December 31 of the previous year
        decPrev = ((year-1)*365+((year-1)/4)-((year-1)/100)+((year-1)/400))%7;

        // adds the days of each month before the month entered
        switch(month)
        {
            case 12:
                decPrev += NOV_DAYS;
            case 11:
                decPrev += OCT_DAYS;
            case 10:
                decPrev += SEP_DAYS;
            case 9:
                decPrev += AUG_DAYS;
            case 8:
                decPrev += JUL_DAYS;
            case 7:
                decPrev += JUN_DAYS;
            case 6:
                decPrev += MAY_DAYS;
            case 5:
                decPrev += APR_DAYS;
            case 4:
                decPrev += MAR_DAYS;
            case 3:
                decPrev += FEB_DAYS;
                if (0 == (year % 4)) decPrev += 1;
            case 2:
                decPrev += JAN_DAYS;
            case 1:
                decPrev += day;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        dayOfWeek = decPrev % 7;

        // translates the number value to a string for the day
        switch(dayOfWeek)
        {
            case 0:
                cout << "The day of the week for " << month << "/"
                << day << "/" << year << " is Sunday" << endl;
                break;
            case 1:
                cout << "The day of the week for " << month << "/"
                << day << "/" << year << " is Monday" << endl;
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "The day of the week for " << month << "/"
                << day << "/" << year << " is Tuesday" << endl;
                break;
            case 3:
                cout << "The day of the week for " << month << "/"
                << day << "/" << year << " is Wednesday" << endl;
                break;
            case 4:
                cout << "The day of the week for " << month << "/"
                << day << "/" << year << " is Thursday" << endl;
                break;
            case 5:
                cout << "The day of the week for " << month << "/"
                << day << "/" << year << " is Friday" << endl;
                break;
            case 6:
                cout << "The day of the week for " << month << "/"
                << day << "/" << year << " is Saturday" << endl;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    else cout << "Invalid input." << endl;
    //Here is the statement which asks the user to continue or not.
    cout<<"Want to continue?";
    cin>>choice;
    //If y or Y is entered, the loop will continue, 
    //otherwise it will terminate.
    } while (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y');
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple looped program works like this (it will run forever):

```
int main()
{
while(true)
    {
    //do stuff
    }
}
```

another alternative is doing this (it will run untill x==0):

```
int main()
{
    do{
      //do stuff
      cin >> x;
     }while(x!=0)
}
```